# What to look for in a thermometer for bread making?

Tags: bread, thermometer

I am trying make wholemeal bread for the first time. I will use the recipe on the back of the wholemeal flour. I don't have any measuring thermometer. It is Winter here and the kitchen might be at 10C. There are thermometers in the shops but they are rather expensive digital thermometers.

Would something like this be suitable? 
https://www.amazon.co.jp/SODIAL-R-AEQW-WER-AW145002-%E6%B8%A9%E5%BA%A6%E8%A8%88%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8-%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B9%E3%83%81%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB-%E6%96%99%E7%90%86%E3%82%92%E8%AA%BF%E7%90%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E7%82%BA-200%E6%91%82%E6%B0%8F/dp/B017TXXV3I/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1545900519&sr=8-7&keywords=thermometer

Comment: What do you want to measure? Room temperature? Water temperature? Dough temperature? Oven temperature?

Comment: As I said I don't know much about bread making- which ones do you think I need.